# Cannot reset botched IDA setting

Tags: ida

[image]
I managed to accidentally modify the opcode column setting of the view window to display the data in word format (2 byte).  For the life of me I cannot seem to figure how to switch if back to byte format.  Resetting the desktop does not work.  I could use some advice.

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is standard format for some processors (such as 68K) and can’t be changed by the user. You can see the separate bytes in the Hex View (synchronize it with IDA View to see the bytes corresponding to the current instruction).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Yes, I am using IDA for some 68K firmware and didn't realize that.  I spent a bunch of time looking for a way to change the setting.  Take care -